# Java HashMaps with only put and get - possibly concurrency issues?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, synchronized

I've worked with ConcurrentHashMaps, but I'm not quite sure if that will cover all of the bases here.

I have a Spring Component. This Component will contain a Map. This will simply be a quick reference for objects in an external service. If the map does not contain a matching String, it will make a call to the external service, retrieve the object, and store it in the mapping. Then other classes can use the mapping for quick retrieval and usage. As such, there are only put() and get() operations performed on the map. Entries are never removed.

That being said, I'm a little concerned that ConcurrentHashMap may not provide the atomic control I'd like. Fetching SomeObject from the external service is potentially expensive. I'd rather not have two separate threads calling in at nearly the same time, resulting in multiple calls for the same value to the external service.

The idea is this:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> map = Collections.concurrentHashMap(
    new HashMap<String, SomeObject>());

public SomeObject getSomeObject(String key){
    if (!map.containsKey(key)){
        map.put(key, retrieveSomeObjectFromService(key));
    }
    return map.get(key);
```

Or this:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> map = new HashMap<String, SomeObject>();

public SomeObject getSomeObject(String key){
    synchronized(map){
        if (!map.containsKey(key)){
            map.put(key, retrieveSomeObjectFromService(key));
        }
    }
    return map.get(key);
}
```

The former is certainly simpler, but the latter would ensure that one two or more threads won't try to simultaneously trigger a fetching of the same SomeObject. Alternatively, I suppose I could try locking out only gets that attempt to retrieve a SomeObject that is already in the process of being fetched and does not block retrieving SomeObjects that already exist, but that would require a wait mechanism on the various string values and I'm not sure how to best implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you do a little bit of both!

Fast path, just 1 get out of the concurrent hashmap.
Slow path, full sync and lock

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public Object getSomeObject(String key) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            value = map.get(key);
            if (value == null) {
                value = retrieveSomeObjectFromService(key);
                map.put(key, value);
            }

        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
    return value;
}
```

Do you understand why we need the 2nd get inside of the lock?  Leaving that out leaves a case where we end up making the inside object twice, and having different copies of it floating around.

Also doing the assign the result to value and nullcheck vs using the contains method - understand why that is better?  If we do a .contains then a .get, we just did 2 hashmap lookup.  If I just do a get, I can cut my hashmap lookup time in half.

Another version Peter suggested.. less lines of code, but not my personal preference:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

public Object getSomeObject(String key) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        synchronized (map) {
            value = map.get(key);
            if (value == null) {
                value = retrieveSomeObjectFromService(key);
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: +1 Though I don't see what lock gives you that synchronized doesn't, the code would be simpler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Your friends blog :)  http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-lock-implementations.html   "ReentrantLock gives the best un-contended performance and scales significantly better with increasing contention compared to language monitors using synchronized."

Comment: Good link though I disagree on the low contended lock performance for Java 6 & 7.  This was true for Java 5 but synchronized has improved since then.  In any case you can say that synchronized is simpler.

Comment: Well if I wanted simple code, I would use Scala with an anonymous function withLock to read just like synchronized, but really use a lock under the hood ;) You are right, the test was JDK6, no guarantees on JDK7 or JDK8 perf. I tend to be slow to change such habbits though

Comment: synchnronized costs is about 300 ns when contended (faster uncontended), the cost of `retrieveSomeObjectFromService` has to be around this level to notice any difference. If it is much more it could be half the speed but you would never know.

Comment: True, but I find it easier to have my team follow "locked is slightly faster than sync, so use locks when you need to sync"  vs "weigh the pros and cons of the exact use case, and use the exact right method in that place."   If my codebase has 50 places where I need one or the other.. I would rather write the 3 extra lines of code of lock (and err on the wasting 3 lines of code side) over saving 3 lines of code but potentially introducing a perf bug down the road.

Comment: I agree to a point.  It is worth noting that when the JVM supports Hardware Transactional Memory it is most likely going to be with `synchronized` first as it is a language feature.  You may find in the future you have to remove all your locks to support HTM. (Adding in the Haswell processor)

Comment: Nice, and thanks for the reminder on doublechecking the map before and after the synchronized/lock. I've dealt with that before, but it slipped my mind here. The performance impact of either isn't a huge deal. Once the map is populated (which will take maybe a dozen fetch operations from the service), new entries won't be added very often, so using map.containsKey(Object) (no need to muck around with a value) before and after a synchronized block should be sufficient.

Comment: @user1017413 if 99.999% of the time your item is in the map, you still don't want to use contains. Would be 1 contains to see if it is there, and then 1 get to get the item out. That is 2 accesses to the hashmap for the common case. Whereas my code above only has 1 access to the hashmap in a common case. Yes O(n) is the same as O(2n), but that kind of bloat can add up in a real project.